# React useEffect doesn't reload my component after state update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I know this problem has been asked several times on stackoverflow but i can't make this work even after trying during several hours ...

I am working with React.js for a year now but I recently moved to React hooks and stateless components so I don't have much experience with them so excuse me in advance if the solution is obvious because I really tried to solve it on my own before asking here ...

**1. What my code is doing :**

I have a simple `useEffect` hook that i want to call when the props `rank` has changed.
In the hook, i am calling `toggleNodeByRank()` method using `.then` and updating my state named `data` once the method has been executed.

**2. What is happenning :**

For now, (almost) everything is working fine and in the second `console.log('===StateUpdated===', chartData);` i can see that my state has the correct updated value.

The only problem is that my component doesn't reload and if I repeat the action that update the `rank` props, I can see the modifications.

I have seen some answers saying that the deps (`rank` here) were not good, I have tried to add `chartData` in the deps aswell (`[rank, chartData]`) but the problem remain the same...

Maybe someone can help me on this one ?

```
useEffect(() => 
  console.log('===PreviousState===', chartData);

  toggleNodeByRank(chartData, rank).then((data) => setChartData(data));

  console.log('===StateUpdated===', chartData);

}, [rank]);
```

**3. Edit**

Here is the toggleNodeByRank() function, since this is my company's code i prefer not to share too much, I hope this can help you guys..

```
  const toggleNodeByRank = async (node, rank) => {
    if (node && node.data) {
      // await update node.children depending on node.rank
      // - If I want to toggle the node :
      // I am saving the node.children in a state object (key = node.id, 
      // value = node.children) and I reset the node.children value to [ ]
      // - If I don't want to toggle the node :
      // I don't do anything and juste render
      // update another state to save the node.children data if needed.
      return node;
    }
  };
```

Comment: please use async await  and pass setChartData in useEffect dependencies. Like. `const data = await  toggleNodeByRank(chartData, rank);   setChartData(data)`

Comment: @ArunkarthiMani You can't use async in `useEffect` unless you use an IIFE, using `async/await`, `chartData` is still the same value, as it got the same scope from the same render cycle

Comment: I can use `async / await` in useEffect only by creating a custom function inside my `useEffect` method like so :
`const data = async () => {
      const tmp = await toggleNodeByRank(chartData, rank);
      return tmp;
    };`
The problem with it is that when I `console.log` the result of the async function I get : `Promise {<pending>}` and I don't know how to fix this ...

Comment: Please show the other code parts as well.

Comment: To see why the component isn't re-rendered. Its important to know what toggleNodeByRank does

Comment: @ford04
@ShubhamKhatri
I've updated the post to add some code about the `toggleNodeByRank` function, please let me know if I can help in any other way...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are mutating the original node element in place instead of updating it in an immutable manner, `setChartData` isn't triggering a re-render as react checks if the value passed to state updater is actually changed from previous value or not and since the reference is same it believes that nothing has changed

According to React principles you must never mutate state values instead update them in an immutable way.

If its possible for you to update the state in an immutable manner, please do that in toggleNodeByRank

However you can still work around by shallow cloning the node like

```
const toggleNodeByRank = async (nodeArg, rank) => {
    const node = {...nodeArg};
    if (node && node.data) {
      return node;
    }
  };
```

After doing the above change, it would trigger a re-rerender but you must know that it isn't the best way

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer !   
I've tried your workaround and it's working like a charm ! I guess that I must learn more about the mutable and immutable notions now ;)

Comment: @olivierdumas As I said though, please try and see if you can update node in an immutable manner. If not then only use the above workaround :-)

Comment: Anyways, glad to have helped :-)

Comment: Sure, I just need to study a bit this notion as I don't know much about it but at least I've got a temporary fix for the moment! Thanks again ;)

Answer (score 0):

You have problem with understanding promises, in you code this 2 console.log will output same value because `(data) => setChartData(data)` is callback witch will be called after toggleNodeByRank is done.
Basically your code executes in this way:

1) console.log('===PreviousState===', chartData);

2) toggleNodeByRank(chartData, rank); //here you just send request

3) console.log('===StateUpdated===', chartData);

4) (data) => setChartData(data)

So everything is fine and second time when u run your component update you see changed `chartData`

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but actually (if I understand well your point) my second console.log has exactly the value that I want, so there is probably another problem with my code because the component doesn't reload event if the state has been updated..